# Can't add a menu item on ExtJS 3.4

Tags: extjs, extjs3

I'm trying the following code to add a menu item at runtime but I can't get it to work, the ExtJS documentation has samples only to create the entire menu along with the menu item.
Any help is much appreciated.

```
var menuItem = Ext.create('Ext.menu.Item', { text: 'menu item'});
```

Error:

```
TypeError: b[e] is not a constructor
Ext.ComponentMgr.create()ext.axd?v=31893 (line 7)
()debugg...al code (line 2)


...;if(a.getMonth()==G.getMonth()&&a.getFullYear()==G.getFullYear()){this.cells.rem...
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're using a syntax from Ext4 for `Ext.create`. In Ext3 the function takes a config object as its first argument, and expects to find a `xtype` in it (see the [doc](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/3.4.0/#!/api/Ext-method-create)).

E.g.

```
var menuItem = Ext.create({xtype: 'menuitem', text: 'menu item'});
```

But you might as well just use the `new` operator:

```
var menuItem = new Ext.menu.Item({text: 'menu item'});
```

Comment: Perfect, would you mind demonstrating how to add a click listener when using this kind of constructor?Thanks

Comment: Exactly the same as Ext4: add a `listeners` object to your config, or use the [`addListener`](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/3.4.0/#!/api/Ext.util.Observable-method-addListener) method later on...